# A type of integer numbers set

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Is there any $A\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ such that $A-A$ is a non-trivial co-finite
subset?

Note that $A-A=\{a_1-a_2: a_1,a_2\in A\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let 
$$ A := \left\{\sum_{k=2}^n k : n \ge 1 \right\} $$ 
Then $A - A = \mathbf Z \setminus \{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: The lower bound of the sigma is $1$, isn't it?

Comment: No, it's not. It's $2$. And (as usual), we have $\sum_{k=2}^1 k = 0$, the empty sum.